# Outlook Web App always pastes copied excel tables as an image

Tags: images, microsoft-excel-2007, copy-paste, outlook-web-access

I'm using Outlook Web App - Version: 14.2.309.3

When I paste a table from Excel 2007 into a new message in OWA, it always pastes it as an image and not as a table.

I have 5 colleagues who use the same software (version too) and they don't get this problem. I've also looked through the settings in detail and see nothing related to this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

While logging into Outlook Web Application did you choose "this is a private computer" and did you use Internet Explorer?

OWA provides some extended capabilities but only on a 'private' computer and only when accessed via IE.